# Remove data that was previously added in App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Hello so I have this Java code for an address book app on android studio where I have the add button so whatever name I type, it gets added into the address book app. I made a delete button so whatever name I type in, if it is already added, it will delete it from the address book data. How would I get the delete button to work

```
public void btnAddData(View v)
{
    String name= firstName.getText().toString();
    String surName= lastName.getText().toString();
    String phone1= phone.getText().toString();

    Person person= new Person();
    person.name=name;
    person.surname=surName;
    person.phone=phone1;
    persons.add(person);
    setTextToTextView();
}

public void btnRemoveData(View v)
{
    //code to delete name 
}

private void setTextToTextView()
{
    String text = "";
    for (int i=0;i<persons.size(); i++)
    {
        text=text + persons.get(i).name+","+persons.get(i).surname+","+persons.get(i).phone+"\n";
    }
    results.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this :-

```
persons.remove(<index or object name>);
```

Comment: so what would replace the index or object, would it be persons.remove(firstName,lastName);

Comment: The name of the object, eg. Here it is person. Or you can get the index of the required element. I would recommend to use a database instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using loop and then remove it.

```
public void btnRemoveData(View v)
{
    String name= firstName.getText().toString();
    for (int i=0;i<persons.size(); i++)
    {
        if(persons.get(i).name.equals(name)) persons.remove(i);
    }
}
```